# Using java script functions in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonconvert, xmlconvert

I am using the below JS library in order to convert a JSON to XML in NodeJS.

[XML.ObjTree](https://www.cnblogs.com/zh33gl/p/5019430.html)

I created a JS file called `XMLJSONParser.js` and added the `XML.ObjTree` content there as below.

`module.exports = function () {
 XML.ObjTree = function () {
        return this;
    };
................ More code
};`

In the controller, I have the below code in order to do the conversion.

```
const XMLs = require('../common/XMLJSONParser');
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
       var { tasks } = req.body;
        var xotree = new XMLs.XML.ObjTree();
        var tree1 = {tasks}
        var xml1 = xotree.writeXML( tree1 );
        alert( "xml1: "+xml1 );
     }
```

When calling I am getting the exception

> message:"Cannot read property 'ObjTree' of undefined"
>   stack:"TypeError: Cannot read property

Am I using the correct way when calling the JS file from Node JS?

I was able to run and get the output in https://js.do properly.

Comment: The `exports` you posted as the first snippet is somehow incomplete, however, it kind of looks like you are exporting **a function**. But then, when you import it, you expect it to be an object with `.XML` property. If this is so, the function surely doesn't have the property so that you are not allowed to further ask for `.ObjTree()`.

Comment: Remove `module.exports = function () {` and add at the bottom of your XMLJSONParser.js file this `module.exports = XML;` the you can do `const XML = require('../common/XMLJSONParser'); XML.ObjTree();`

Answer (score 0):

`XML` is `undefined`  so define `XML`

```
module.exports = function () {
 let XML = {};
 XML.ObjTree = function () {
        return this;
    };
................ More code
};
```